# Can I use border-radius on border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

i want to ask, is it possible to use border-radius on border-bottom?

I want to do like this: http://prntscr.com/cefbvs

Comment: border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;

Comment: That’s not even a border. That’s a separate rectangle with rounded corners. What have you tried?

Comment: no. But you should take a look into **[Pseudo Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)**. You can achive that fairly simple with them

Comment: @Xufox i have done like this http://prntscr.com/ceff5i, just border, and then border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

just change the background color to what you want and change the radius em to what you want

```css
border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
    background: #036;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
```

Answer (score 0):

"border-radius" has nothing to do with "border".
You can set a border-radius for a div-container e.g. without setting a border.